# Is there built-in option to show "Similar" not identical rows to one?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

As example there is much rows with texts from the web. Can I tell (run some query) to Mysql/Sqlite by saying that I need similar texts (rows) to this one certain text (row)?

When identical is

```
"some string" == "some string"
"some string" != "another string"
```

Similarity is more flexible

```
"some string" ~= "some string"
"some string" ~= "another string"
```

Will be nice if there is range by relevance.

Comment: You're looking for "Full Text Search"

Comment: Do a search for fuzzy match.